# FB Pixel PageView count is 0

Tags: facebook, ads

I'm new to Facebook advertising and i'm trying to set up basic FB Pixel tracking for my website. After setup I see that FB pixel getting loaded successfully, but what I see the PageView count is zero. Please see the attached screenshot (PageView at bottom showing 0). Guys please help what is going wrong here or it takes some time to reflect the count. TIA[image: ![FB Pixel dashboard]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJw8z.png)

Also here is the script which I've placed in header tag.

```
<script>
      !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
      n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
      n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
      t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
      document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

      fbq('init', 'MY_PIXEL_ID');
      fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
      <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
        src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=MY_PIXEL_ID&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
      /></noscript>
```

Comment: Looks like it went from 0 on June 6, to 18 tracked visits on June 7 - so it looks like the problem is solved now(?)

Comment: Ya just checked it after few hours the counts start reflecting. Thanks anyway :)